# Permission denied when attempting to write to a file

Tags: file, ms-access, vba, filesystemobject

I am running a loop that outputs a string variable to a file. Every run of the loop changes the string. On some of the loop's runs, I get an error **Invalid procedure call or function**.

`rst` is a recordset of a table, `fl` is an object which I set as a file like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject(fileType)
Set fl = fso.createtextfile(path)
```

This is the loop:

```
Do Until rst.EOF
            start = rst.Fields(fieldName))
            fl.writeLine start
            rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: How is `start` declared? If it currently is a Variant, can you try declaring it as String? And then use `start = Nz(rst.Fields(fieldName), "")`

Comment: @andre start is declared as a string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create the file:

```
Dim fso as Object
Dim f1 as Object
Dim fileType as String
Dim path as String
Dim myFile as Byte

fileType = "Scripting.FileSystemObject"
path = "C:\myFolder\fileName"
Set fso = CreateObject(fileType)
Set fl = fso.createtextfile(path)
```

**path -** Make sure path leads to a folder to which you have read/write permission. The following instructions are good for windows 7-10 as far as I know. They are probably good for XP as well.

1. Right-click the folder (in this example the folder is "myFolder" in drive C)
2. Click Properties
3. Click the Security tab
4. In the box under **Group or user names** is a list of the pc's users. **System** is the default system user, ignore that. Click on your user. If you are an administrator you can click on **Administrators** instead.
5. Under **Permissions for >user<** is a list of all the actions that can be done with files, and a check in the **Allow** column, if this user has permission to do this action. Otherwise a check will be in the **Deny** column.
6. To change the permissions click on the **Edit...** button that is under **Group or other user names:**

Make sure you close the file after creating it to enable read/write.

```
f1.close
set f1 = Nothing
```

Now you can open the file and add lines to the end of it without deleting previous lines.

```
myFile = FreeFile
Open path For Output As #myFile
Write #myFile, "Something or other " & chr(9) & variableName & rst.Fields(0).Value
```

- `#myFile` is the name we give the file in the code
- `write` is a command that adds a line after the last line in the file.

You can concatenate different variable types with `&`, as long as they can be converted [implicitly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx) to a string/char type. I used:

- a string: `"something or other"`
- a character: `chr(9)`, a tab character
- a variable: `variableName`, string type
- The contents of the first field in `rst` recordset: `rst.Fields(0).Value`. In the brackets  `rst.Fields().Value` you can put`1` for the second field, `2` for the third field and so on. Or a string `"columnName"`.

After you finish looping and writing to the file, make sure you close it.

```
Close #myFile
```

Comment: You don't need to create the file with FSO if you're using the `Open` command, Also it is better to use the `FreeFile()` method to get the next available file number than assume `#1` will always be free. You can also `Open For Append` instead of `Output` and finally `Set f1 = Nothing` is not the closing the file, it's releasing the object from system memory - you should use `f1.Close` for that instead.

Comment: @Macro Man, Thanks! I Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `Open` command instead:

```vb
Dim FF As Byte

FF = FreeFile

Open "C:\Users\MacroMan\SomeFolder\myTextFile.txt" For Output As #FF
    '// Rest of code here
    start = rst.Fields(fieldName)
    Print #FF, start
    '// Rest of code here
Close #FF
```

Comment: I tried this, but keep on getting a message that I don't have permission to write in the file. I checked the file's properties, and I do have permission to read and write to the file.

Comment: Where is the file located? And have you used the `FreeFile` command correctly before opening a file for output?

Comment: To clarify, you should use this instead of `FileSystemObject` - if you've opened the file with FSO it will be locked and therefore you won't be able to write to it.

Comment: if I use your code, a myTextfile.txt  will be created if it doesn't exist? I used `FileSystemObject ` to create the file.

Comment: Yes the file will be created automatically with this code. No need to create it.

Comment: I see you unaccepted this as the answer - does it not solve your issue?